# A function as an argument in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

Is it possible to pass a function as an argument of other function in OpenGL Shading Language? And if it is, then how could it be done?

Comment: As BadZen said: no in general. Your only option would be to use #define macros in creative ways.

Answer (score 5):

Simply put: no.   Functions are not first-class types (or types at all) in GLSL/Cg, and your hardware can't "see through" pointers or the like - the source of your shader is passed as text to the OpenGL VM and compiled there.

(Edited to reflect @datenwolf's correction of my mistake - he says the driver component of the GL virtual machine does the compilation.)

Comment: The source text **is not** parsed and compiled by the GPU. This all happens in the driver. As a matter of fact the NVidia drivers are first translating GLSL source code into `ARB_…_program` or `NV_…_program` pseudo-assembly source code (with a built-in, modified Cg compiler) and then this text undergoes a second compilation stage translating it first into IR code and finally from there GPU binary. Only this binary is then uploaded to the GPU.

Comment: Huh, interesting.  Could you provide a source on this?  I was under the impression that the actual hardware did the compilation and can't find a good explanation of the details - would love to know the exact process.    In any case, s/GPU/GL Virtual Machine/ in what I said above, my point stands - different address space and the language has no first class pointer/function type nor computed calls.

Comment: I didn't downvote. As for where this is stated… I think no specification does state it, because it's so obvious. The whole point of having a compilers is to be able to update the language, work around architecture bugs and improve the code generation without having to replace the hardware. Anyway, nothing forbids a OpenGL implementation to have the compiler done silicon structures on the GPU die; but nobody does it because it makes no sense. Writing a compiler as software is already as hard as it gets. Making it hardware is just pure masochism. Also https://www.khronos.org/spir

Comment: Huh ok.  I thought it was the other way b/c I remember reading that somewhere - and I definitely get different compiler errors from Mesa using different cards (sometimes syntax is slightly different) and the cards contain the GPU model string...  maybe that's coming from some lower level driver though, and I read wrong, or misunderstood.   OpenGL itself def. does not specify, you're correct about that.